# Existence of a system of three linear equations in three variables that has exactly two solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Does there exist a system of three linear equations in three variables that has exactly two solutions?

Comment: the solutions of a linear system form a vector space.

Comment: Can it be that $3$ planes intersect in exactly two points ?

Comment: depends on the vector space. (hint: $\mathbb{F}_2$)

Comment: What is  F2 mean?

Comment: I assume that you are in the reals because otherwise, you should have added some more informations. In this case, there are only $3$ possibilities : no solution , exactly one solution , infinite many solutions. Exactly two solutions is impossible.

Comment: @GCab . Nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

If we are in $\mathbb R^n$, this is not possible. We can write the system as

$$A\vec x =\vec b$$

Now suppose $\vec x_1\neq\vec x_2$ are solutions. Let $\vec x_3=\frac 12\vec x_1+\frac 12\vec x_2$. We can check if $\vec x_3$ is a solution.

$$A\vec x_3=A(\frac 12\vec x_1+\frac 12\vec x_2)=\frac 12A\vec x_1+\frac 12A\vec x_2=\frac 12\vec b+\frac 12\vec b=\vec b$$

$$A\vec x_3=\vec b$$

Thus we have a distinct third vector that is also a solution. In fact, there must be infinitely many solutions, since we can consider any affine combination $\alpha\vec x_1+\beta\vec x_2,\ \ \alpha+\beta=1$.

Answer (score 1):

As Max was hinting, it depends on what underlying field you define your linear system of equations is. As the others mentioned, it is not true for $\mathbb{R}^3$. But you can think of cases in $\mathbb{F}_2^3$ where this could happen (By $\mathbb{F}_2$ I mean the field of boolean numbers with usual sum and multiplication mod 2). Consider the following two linear equations: $x+y+z = 1$ and $z = 1$ where $x,y$ and $z$ are boolean variables and the sums are mod 2. Obviously, you can make it three equations by repeating one of them. For any solution to that linear systems of equations $x+y = 0$ but in $\mathbb{F}_2^2$ only $(x=0, y=0)$ and $(x=1, y=1)$ satisfy those conditions. In other words, there are only 2 solutions.